# Is this field should have a default value?

Tags: reactjs, default-value

I'm a little confused on deciding whether a field should have a default value or not.

We're working on a React Project (probably unrelated with the question), and we're in a debate whether an exact prop should have a default value or not.

I'm unable to find a reference/ theories about this matter.

The exact problem is that we're creating a component for NavigationBottom. I think that component shouldn't have a default value for its routes, as the user should describe the routes, and the routes should be a required props. While my coworkers thinks otherwise.

I hope someone can help get me a reference about this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if a user hasn't described the routes yet? Having default routes is fine depending on use cases and what is needed. Your question doesn't have a lot of information to give a good answer though

Comment: As a general approach, I've been following the [Airbnb's react style guide](https://github.com/airbnb/javascript/tree/master/react) recommendation to provide defaults for any non-required props. By extension, default props should only be for non-required props: if you can provide a meaningful and sensible default then the prop is not required; if you need to specify a prop to make the component behave properly then you probably can't set a meaningful default. Also a default value will prevent PropTypes from warning you when a prop is not specified, so it seems to defeat the purpose.

Comment: @JohnRuddell I can't imagine anyone using a NavigationBottom component without knowing the routes. And if the dev doesn't know yet what's the routes is, they should provide the dummy data. Not inside the component. It's my opinion, though...